# Prove that $dim(S) = Trace(P_S)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $S$ be a subspace of $R^n$ and let $P_S$ be an orthogonal projection onto $S$.

How can I prove that $dim(S) = Trace(P_S)$?

Not sure if this helps with the proof but $P_S$ can be re-written as a matrix $VV^T$

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the fact that $ trace(P_S) $ is the sum of the eigenvalues?  Because it's very easy to find all the eigenvalues of $ P_S $.  Indeed, you can construct an eigenbasis simply by taking any orthonormal basis $ v_1, ..., v_n $ where $ v_1, ..., v_{\dim S} $ is a basis for $ S $.  Can you see what the eigenvalues of these vectors are?  What is $ P_S(v_i) $?

Comment: Can you show how trace($P_S$) is the sum of the eigenvalues?

Comment: That's more of an "important theorem" in linear algebra.  If you haven't been taught it, then you're probably not supposed to use it.

Comment: How else have you been taught to calculate Trace?  Have you learned that it is "invariant under change of basis"?  That too could work, because you could change basis to the one that I described above.  The matrix under that basis would be $ \rm{diag} (1,...,1, 0, ..., 0) $

Comment: Is it spectral theorem? Either way can you explain how you used this theorem? I probably have learned it

Comment: No, spectral theorem is about self-adjoint operators (symmetric matrices, as you might call them in your class/book).  What I cited is more general, applies to all matrices.  If you don't understand my answer above, it probably boils down to you not knowing (well enough) the definitions of one or more of the following words: "trace", "projection onto a subspace", "orthonormal", "basis", "orthonormal basis", "dimension", "eigenvalue", "eigenvector".  I am pretty sure if you *really* know all those things, my answer should make perfect sense.

Comment: Ive learned these topics but am not getting towards your conclusion, so i guess I dont really know them lol

Comment: Show that $ P_S(v_i) = v_i $ for $ v_i \in S $ and $ P_S(v_i) = 0 $ for $ v_i \notin S $.  It then follows that the eigenvalues associated with the $ v_i \in S $ are all $ 1 $'s whereas the eigenvalues associated with the $ v_i \notin S $ are all zeros.  How many 1's do you have?  How many zero's do you have?  Add them all up.  You get the trace.